# Probability - Pairwise independent

Tags: probability

Suppose A and B are pairwise independent events, and suppose B and C are pairwise independent events. Is A and C pairwise independent?

How can we justify this? I feel it purely depends on the events that we take. However can there be a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: Take for instance $A=C$ (not trivial) and $B$ empty...

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking exactely. As answered below, and as I think you already knew, $A$ and $C$ can be dependent. So in general you need to check. To 'show' mathematically that they are not independent/dependent you'd show that the indepenfence condition is satisfied/not satisfied, in your problem.

Comment: @AnyAD True. I also understand A and C can be dependent events. But I have been asked to prove this mathematically. That's where I am struck

Comment: Show simply that probability of $ A\cap B$ is not equal to the product of probability of $A$ and probability of $B $. This is not really a 'proof', more a verification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ and $C$ *can* of course be pairwise dependent, I'll assume that you're asking whether it follows from the premise that $A$ and $C$ are pairwise independent. It does not. For instance, if $A$ and $B$ are any pairwise independent events and $C$ is $A$, then the premise is trivially satisfied, and yet, unless $A$ has probability $0$ or $1$, it is not independent of itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can there be any mathematical proof for this?

Comment: @Learner: I'm not sure I understand your concept of a mathematical proof. In my understanding of that term, what I wrote is a mathematical proof.